# Opensource web apps to run locally

Tags: web-applications, cloud, devops, open-source, cicd

I am learning devops and want to learn cicd etc. i dont have web apps to try. Can anyone suggest me webapps open source that i can run locally and then cicd it. Suggest some apps which are from different frameworks like django,spring boot, flask, node, express etc
Thanks